# rticles: How to have citations not processed by pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown

When using the `rticles` package, citations are already processed in the `.tex` file. For example: In the template for the Elsevier article there is this line:

```
Here are two sample references: @Feynman1963118 [@Dirac1953888].
```

In the `.tex` file created it appears as

```
Here are two sample references: Feynman and Vernon Jr. (1963; Dirac
1953).
```

This means that the references were processed prior to the latex compilation (probably by Pandoc). How can I have the citations handled by Latex instead? I want the file `.tex` file created to have something like:

```
Here are two sample references: \citet{Feynman1963118} \citep{Dirac1953888}.
```

Is there an option to achieve that?